# Navigation Controller Back Functionality

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an 3 view A B C both three have an navigation bar. my need is when i click on C view Back button i want to open A view but Problem is this when i back to A. At A's Navigation Bar Adding C back button.

I tried this one

```
UIBarButtonItem * back=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(move)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=back;

-(void)move
{

    FirstViewController * fvc=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];

    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:fvc animated:NO];


}
```

please help me out this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Controller are pushed into stack at index 0,1,2 like this that means FirstViewController At 0 index,SecondViewController At 1 index as it is.

so you may try this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

0 index For your First View Controller.

Try this one really Helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem * back=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(move)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=back;
```

if you want to push on another view controller then use this

```
-(void)move
{
     FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:YES];

}
```

if you want to back to the previously screen then use this code

```
-(void)move
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: code work for me but at first view controller navigation bar back button add.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, tell me that you want to go back or want to move on next screen ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:VCIndex] animated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

tyr this one

```
 -(void)Back
 {
        NSArray *array1 = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array1 objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
 //  objectAtIndex put your as requirement like 0,1,2 etc..

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-(void)move
 {

    [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 }
```